# How do you unpickle a python object in Java

Tags: java, python, pickle, xgboost

I am trying unpickle an xgboost model within Java to load it. Is there any way to do this. It’s difficult for me to run purely in python.

I’ve been thinking of programmatically writing and executing a python script but is there a cleaner way? Solutions like Jython are outdated because I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: The format that is used when you use pickle an object in Python is not easy to read in other languages. Better solution: Unpickle it in Python, and then store it using a common, standard format such as JSON, which can easily be read from Java.

Comment: `pickle` is programming language-specific encoding, try language-agnostic encoding like JSON, XML.

Answer (score 3):

See the awesome [Pickle](https://github.com/irmen/pickle) library.

The usage is very simple:

```
Object pyObject;
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("dump.pkl")){
  net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler unpickler = new net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler();
  pyObject = unpickler.load(is);
}
```

If the pickle file contains a Python object, then the loaded `pyObject` is a Java map that contains key-value attribute mappings.